# How to decrypt encrypted files in windows 8.1?

Tags: encryption, certificate, key, windows-8.1, digital-certificate

I encrypted some files in order to hide them, but I didn't know about it much and didn't do things right I guess. (from 'advanced' option i.e. beside the hidden attribute in properties)

So now I cant access these files as they show: I don't have permissions to access them.

I tried to import certificates from 'personal' store in 'crtmgr.msc' to that folder where these files belong. But failed (a pfx file was generated/exported and I imported it again too).

P.S: *And one more thing, I had to reset my windows 8.1 after I encrypted them once. Hope someone from here can definitely help me if possible. Thanks.*

Comment: What tool did you use to encrypt the files?

Comment: from 'advanced' option i.e. beside the hidden attribute in properties(general tab)